# Travel to Brazil with US visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, brazil

May I know if I can travel to Brazil with US L1 visa. I hold an Indian passport. Do I need separate visa for Brazil or will L1 be suffice.

Comment: Brazil is not in the United States.

Comment: There are very few situations in which having a visa for one country allows you to travel to another.  Normally in a case like this, you should start by ignoring your existing visa and looking up the procedure for an Indian citizen to travel to Brazil, to see if a visa is needed.  If there's a special exception for people with US visas, you will most likely see it mentioned along the way.  Usually there isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Brazil does require visas for Indian citizens, and U.S. visas are not sufficient.

This is not a ridiculous question, however, as many countries allow foreign nationals entry with U.S. visas.  Mexico allows entry with only a U.S. visa, though they also issue Mexican visas, and Turkey allows evisa entry to nationals of all Arab League countries who hold a U.S. visa.

While it might seem patently obvious that Brazil is a separate country, and would therefore have separate visas, not all countries have the infrastructure to issue visas worldwide.  Accepting U.S. visas in lieu of or in addition to border-issued visas is one strategy, since the U.S. personally interviews and screens nearly all visa applicants.